# How to automatically fill a DataGridView with an active directory request

Tags: c#, datagridview, active-directory

I am trying to fill a DataGridView from a `searchResult.FindAll()`

I do a user search by lastname in the Active Directory, when multiple users have the same lastname I would like the datagrid to open and fill with all users who have the same lastname.

I can detect the number of results and put information in the `DataGridView` but the problem is that the table is filled with the same user each time and not with all users who has the same name

Thank's for your help

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     if (!row.IsNewRow)
     {
            string RNom = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://d21.tes.local", Gid, mdp);
            DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
            searcher.Filter = "(sn=" + RNom + ")";




            foreach (SearchResult result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                    DirectoryEntry DirEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    if (searcher.FindAll().Count > 1)
                    {
                        dataGridView2.RowCount = searcher.FindAll().Count;
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView2.Rows)
                        {
                            DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
                            SearchResultCollection resultat = ds.FindAll();
                            foreach (SearchResult sr in resultat)
                            {
                                r.Cells[0].Value = DirEntry.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                                r.Cells[1].Value = DirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
                                r.Cells[2].Value = DirEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
                                r.Cells[3].Value = DirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
           }
           else
           {
                    row.Cells[0].Value = DirEntry.Properties["SAMAccountName"].Value.ToString();
                    row.Cells[1].Value = DirEntry.Properties["sn"].Value.ToString();
                    row.Cells[2].Value = DirEntry.Properties["givenName"].Value.ToString();
                    row.Cells[3].Value = DirEntry.Properties["mail"].Value.ToString();
           }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

These problems are affecting your results:

1. That code won't compile. Maybe it's just a copy/paste error, but it looks like the `else` should be inside the `foreach`, not outside.
2. The main problem is that you are writing the results in the same row. You are looping through all the results, without moving on to the next row. And then in the next row, you're doing it all again (performing another search and writing all the results in the same row). So every row will be the same, showing only the last result.
3. You are overwriting the same `dataGridView2` each time. You should set `dataGridView2` to something new each time.
4. You are running a second search (`ds.FindAll()`) with no actual query string - and those are the results you're using. You want to use the results from your first search (`searcher.FindAll()`)

These issues are affecting your performance:

5. You are calling `searcher.FindAll()` three times. This will go out to AD and perform the exact same search three times.
6. Using `result.GetDirectoryEntry()` makes it go out to AD and get the attributes again instead of using the data retrieved by the search, which will just slow down your code for no benefit. You can use `result.Properties` to use the data returned in the search instead.
7. You can set [`DirectorySearcher.PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload) to limit the attributes returned. If you don't set it, all attributes with a value will be returned, which is unnecessary. You can speed things up by asking for only what you need.
8. When you use [`DirectorySearcher.FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall), the documentation says you need to dispose the results, otherwise you will end up with a memory leak.

I've attempted to correct those issues here (except for `dataGridView2` - you will have to figure that out):

```
string RNom = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

DirectoryEntry ldapConnection = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://d21.tes.local", Gid, mdp);
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(ldapConnection);
searcher.Filter = "(sn=" + RNom + ")";

searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SAMAccountName");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenName");
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

using (var results = searcher.FindAll())
{
    if (results.Count > 1)
    {
        var dataGridView2 = ??; //You need to set this to something different each time, otherwise you will just overwrite it
        dataGridView2.RowCount = results.Count;
        var rowId = 0;
        foreach (SearchResult result in results)
        {
            var r = dataGridView2.Rows[rowId];
            r.Cells[0].Value = result.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0];
            r.Cells[1].Value = result.Properties["sn"][0];
            r.Cells[2].Value = result.Properties["givenName"][0];
            r.Cells[3].Value = result.Properties["mail"][0];

            rowId++;
        }
    }
    else if (results.Count == 1)
    {
        var result = results[0];
        row.Cells[0].Value = result.Properties["SAMAccountName"][0];
        row.Cells[1].Value = result.Properties["sn"][0];
        row.Cells[2].Value = result.Properties["givenName"][0];
        row.Cells[3].Value = result.Properties["mail"][0];
    }
    else
    {
        //no results
    }
}
```

If you want to read more about how to optimize performance when communicating with AD, I wrote an article on the subject: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Indeed it's the first time that I use the communication and I was lost in all the available functions. I'm going to read your article =)

Comment: Happy to help! I forgot to mention in my answer that you didn't handle the case where you get no results, although I did include that in the code.